# How to Build Bounding Box of Voronoi Diagram

Tags: java, javascript, ruby, voronoi

I need to build bounding box of a Voronoi Diagram.
my problem is "how to attach half-infinite edge to it".

I use Fortune's Algorithm to calcutate diagram and i follow " Computional Geometry" by de Berg, Cheong, van Kreveld and Overmars.

Probably, my geometry knowledge is very bad, but i don't know to do it!

does someone know any algorithm to build bounding box?

Comment: We don't know what code you've written, and have no way to build upon it, so we really can't give you any sort of decent answer.